# JavaFX Layout behaviour on resize

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

First of all I'd like to show you some photos, so you can better understand my problem.
[image: Not resized window]

[image: Resized to fullscreen]

[image: fxml configuration]

I want to show a small arrow above my PieChart. This arrow should point to the center of the PieChart. When I start my application it looks fine, but when I resize the window to fullscreen the arrow goes far to the right. My ImageView lies in a AnchorPane->BorderPane(TOP) and I set the Anchor Constraints for the right and the top side. The PieChart lies also in an AnchorPane -> BorderPane(Center). There I set all 4 Anchor Constraints. But also when set all Anchor Constraints for the ImageView the resizing does not work.

Anbody has an idea how I can solve this resizing problem ? Maybe I can bind the position of the imageView to the one from the PieChart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `VBox`, set the alignment to `CENTER`, and place the arrow and the pie chart in the `VBox`.